# Wordpress - Tag glossary with descriptions and contents

Tags: wordpress, tags

This is a rather complicated one, so I'm sort of expecting this to sink without a trace - but worth a go.

What I'm looking to do is have a Tags page which has a table of contents (tags list). When clicking on a tag in the table of contents, you would skip down the page to the relevant tag (using an anchor?). Here it would display the chosen tag name with its tag description and link to the tag page.

Any ideas on how I could implement this would be greatly appreciated. I've combed the Wordpress codex and Stackoverflow and not found much documentation on echoing tag lists in this way.

Thanks in advance anyone who can help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [get_tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tags) functions to get all the tags, make a ul with them with links to their slugs(or anything unique) and then display them with something like this (slightly modified version of the codex example)

```
$tags = get_tags();
$html = '<div id='anchor_{$tag->slug}' class="post_tags">';
foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
    $tag_link = get_tag_link( $tag->term_id );

   $html .= "<a href='{$tag_link}' title='{$tag->name} Tag' class='{$tag->slug}'>";
    $html .= "{$tag->name}</a>";
}
$html .= '</div>';
echo $html;
```